# javascript filter on data like ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a custom filter in native javascript, any ideas on how this can be implemented in the light of angular [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="search" onChange='filter()'>
```

**JS**

```
List.prototype.init = function(list) {
    data = list;
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].first));
        li.appendChild(h1);
        li.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        this.element.appendChild(li);
    }
};


var filter = function() {
      /// data is available here
}
```

Comment: Try using `ng-change` or `ng-blur` equivalents to the native javascript events.

Comment: Thanks Martin but I'm looking for a native solution in plain js

Comment: ah, ok, sorry. In light of angular, it is imo a different task, because of angular being declarative using templates and native javascript imperative using DOM functions.

Comment: you may ignore in light of angular, maybe in plain js how'd you approach this?

Comment: The `init` function could have another parameter for the filter, inside it could first delete DOM created previosly and then recreate it with data from the filtered list.

Comment: do you recommend `ul.innerHTML = ''` or traverse it?

Comment: yep, the first option is ok